# How can I type hint SQLAlchemy Queries?

Tags: python, types, sqlalchemy, typing, pylance

I'm using Pylance (with type hints powered by PyRight) in VSCode, and have the following function:

```
def sample(session: sqlalchemy.orm.Session) -> sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query:
    return session.query((MyModel)
```

When looking at Pylance's type inferences, this function actually has the return type of Query[Unknown].  When I change the type hint to `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query[MyModel]`, Pylance correctly can deduce relevant types for it.  this is great! Until I actually run the code, and get `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`.

It makes sense why I get this error, but it seems like there must be some way to make this work, otherwise Pylance is just taunting me.  One workaround (which does work) I have found is this:

```
def sample(session: sqlalchemy.orm.Session) -> (
    sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query[MyModel]
    if typing.TYPE_CHECKING
    else sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query
):
    return session.query(MyModel)
```

but this is obviously awful and I hate it.  I might be able to make a helper function that extracts that and is more readable, but I really feel like this should be possible without an awful workaround!

Comment: Doc for type hint support in SQLA 1.4 https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html

Answer (score 7):

```py
def sample(session: sqlalchemy.orm.Session) -> 
"sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query[MyModel]":
    return session.query(MyModel)
```

actually works just fine and I feel dumb.  If there is any other way I'd be happy to accept that answer!